# Existe necessidade de declarar a mesma dependência no Gemfile e no gemspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem

Tenho diversas engines em minha API, todas tem como dependência o `Artemis::Core`.

Quero entender a diferença entre declarar no `Gemfile`, por exemplo, a gem `artemis-core`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'artemis-core', '~> 0.0.1'

gemspec
```

E declarar no a mesma gem no arquivo `gemspec`:

```
$LOAD_PATH.push File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)

require 'artemis/support/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'artemis-support'
  s.version     = Artemis::Support::VERSION
  s.authors     = ['Secret Name']
  s.email       = ['secret@example.com']
  s.summary     = 'Secret summary'

  s.files = Dir['{app,config,db,lib}/**/*', 'Rakefile', 'README.md']

  s.add_dependency 'rails', '~> 5.0.2', '>= 5.0.2'
  s.add_dependency 'artemis-core', '~> 0.0.1'

  s.add_development_dependency 'pg', '~> 0.20'
end
```

Sei que automaticamente o `gemspec` herda as gems declaradas no `Gemfile`.

Existe alguma regra especial para essas situações? Obrigado.

Comment: Isso influencia nas dependência que irão ser instaladas pelo host?

Comment: Fazendo alguns testes entendi melhor, para esse exemplo o que vai para o `Gemfile` será utilizado para desenvolver a gem, e o que vai para o `gemspec` será utilizado para rodar a gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O arquivo gemspec ele está enraizado no código ruby, como um boot da gem, é nele que fica o 'setting' do são as dependências exigidas para o correto funcionamento da gem.

Com o advento do bundler criou-se o Gemfile que é um super gerenciador de depedência para ruby.

Com isso seu contexto fica da seguinte forma:

Você tem que carregar sua core no gemspec, mas o gemspec não tem funcionalidades o bastante para agregar itens como path, github e etc.. No máximo diferencia runtime e development.

No seu caso, carregue sua gem acima da chamada gemspec no Gemfile com tudo que você precisa (path, version, branch) e no gemspec repita a chamada com require_dependency 'x'

O gemfile é chamado antes do gemspec se o bundle já conter uma versão da gem core setada, o gempsec vai conseguir fazer a carga da mesma.

Outro item que vem como default é que seu gemfile seta tudo para :development, o que da a entender algo como gems do Gemfile está para um enviroment :development e gems do gemspec estão pra :production.